Unable to open a new webcam connection in OpenCV from a while loop
I'm trying to make an application that can switch between webcam feeds. I put the webcam functionality into a Class, and it creates the VideoCapture object when the class is created.
When I initialize the Class outside of a While loop, it has no problems opening the VideoCapture. When I try to create the Class inside a while loop (in the example below it's just for an input, the input is the index of the camera), it fails to open the VideoCapture properly.
EDIT: Based on comments I added a thread.join in the stop() function, and also just an exaggerated number of print statements in the stop to make sure everything there was cleaning up before we moved on to making the new CamObj
class CamObj:
    """
    Class that continuously acquires images from a camera.
    """

    def __init__(self, index):
        self.error = False
        self.index = index
        print(self.index, " Camera created")

        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(self.index)
        (self.got_frame, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

        if not self.stream.isOpened():
            print(self.index, " NOT OPENED")

        self.running = True
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.get_frames_loop)
        print(self.index , " Camera starting")
        self.thread.start()

    def get_frames_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            if not self.got_frame:
                print(self.index , " NO FRAME")
                self.stop()
            else:
                #print("Running")
                (self.got_frame, self.frame) = self.stream.read()


    def stop(self):
        print(self.index , " Is stopping")
        self.running = False
        print(self.index , " Joining")
        self.thread.join()
        print(self.index , " Releasing")
        self.stream.release()
        print(self.index , " Released")


def run():
    camera = CamObj(0) # good, works
    camera = CamObj(1) # also works
    while True:
        index = input("\n Enter camera index: ")
        camera.stop()
        camera = CamObj(index) # fails to open the capture


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

I checked that it works sequentially outside of a while loop. (see CamObj0 and CamObj1)
I tried every webcam index that works on my pc (currently testing with 4)
I tried just changing the index by doing the following function instead:
def change_index(self, index):
    self.stream.release()
    self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(self.index)
    if not self.stream.isOpened():
        print(self.index + " NOT OPENED")


i think you should change your approach here, you want to change the camera index but you are currently creating a new instance every time you change index. So, you are calling init over and over and defines then runs a thread but i am not sure what happens to the previous thread meanwhile. This is too complicated, by defining a function for changing index (change_index()) whole process becomes much cleaner and you dont define and run a thread over and over.

camera.stop() on the old object should be good enough if you join on the thread in the stop() method -- the approach is fine. there's no inherent issue in starting and stopping threads. the VideoCapture has to be recreated anyway, and that's the most expensive part.

@BarışAktaş That's what I had actually initially tried, just changing the index, but hit the same issue there first. I resorted to basically destroying the old object and starting from scratch just to get something working... but clearly that didn't work either so I'm in a pickle.

Enter camera index:  0
NO FRAME1
1 Is stopping
Is stopping1
1 Joining
Joining1
1 Releasing
Releasing1
1 Released
Released0
Camera created
0  NOT OPENED
0  Camera starting
0
